# Populate a ComboBox value in a loop?

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

Hi I am trying to run some code that assigns a combobox a value from a single cell in a range of cells and then executes some formulas on my worksheet and then finally prints a pdf of the output sheet. Everything seems to be working ok, except that the final pdf does not display the value I am running in the combobox (although the sheet calculations have been applied). It may be that my loop executes faster than my combobox can display the value. I'm not really sure. Below is my code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim FileName As String

Set ws = Sheets("Multi")
Set wsEE = Sheets("Employee")

FileName = ws.Range("B2")

    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 7 To LastRow

        wsEE.ComboBox4.Value = ws.Range("A" & i)

        wsEE.Activate
        Application.Calculate

        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=ws.Range("B2") & "TCC Analysis - " & ws.Range("A" & i) & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False

    Next i

ws.Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I also have some code that runs on combobox change. I'm not sure if this could also be part of my problem. Here is that code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox4_Change()

Sheets("Employee").Range("AZ1") = ComboBox4.Value

Application.Calculate

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Employee")

If Me.ComboBox4 <> -1 Then
    ws.Range("C72").Value = ws.Range("C16").Value
    ws.Range("C73").Value = ws.Range("C19").Value
End If

Application.Calculate

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Has anyone experienced this problem before? Does anyone have a solution they can provide? Thank you!

Comment: It may be something to do with `ScreenUpdating` I've had issues with objects in the past due to this being turned off. I wonder if the excel view needs to update for the pdf to print with the changes correctly. Can you try commenting out the `ScreenUpdating` lines and try again

Comment: Yes. I will test removing ScreenUpdating and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: No. Removing ScreenUpdating had no impact.

Comment: ok. Try putting `DoEvents` after the `ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat`

Comment: I tried DoEvents after ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat within the loop, but same problem.

Comment: Does the error occurs when you debug macro slowly by F8? Maybe things happens really too fast and you have to wait let's say a second before printing pdf.

Comment: I'm not sure how to debug the macro slowly. I have tried walking through the logic and testing a few alternate scenarios without any luck. How would I go about slowing the macro down further - say a second?

Comment: When I test without Pdf it displays the last value in the combobox, but I suppose I am not sure if it is displaying each value through each iteration.

Comment: You can press F8 to execute code line by line. Slowly, I mean don't press key and keep it pressed down ;)

Comment: When I run each line of code with F8 there is no issue. I suppose this would mean I need to slow the code processing down by delaying a second...

Comment: Great, I added a 10 second delay and this did not work either. Perhaps, there is a property I need to change on the combobox...or something else...

Comment: My last suggestion: add delay and delete `ScreenUpdating`. It is always turned off by default when you debug. Try to add delay in few places in code.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. Thank you.

Comment: It didn't work, but I am stumped.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the issue. The combobox property Locked was set to True. Setting Locked = False appears to have corrected my problem. Thanks!